# How do I send text to the display on a DataLogic Gryphon barcode scanner using Micosoft POS.NET

Tags: c#, barcode, display

I'm working on a barcode scanner application in c# and are using Microsoft POS 1.14 to communicate with the scanner. Barcode scanning works fine but now our customers want to use scanners with a display to show "friendly" text instead of the barcode.

I have not found any code example on how to do this, I hope it is possible. Maybe the "DirectIO"-command could be used but unfortunatly I could not get it to work.

In DataLogic's Product Reference Guide you can find "escape-sequences" that could be sent to the scanner probably this could be the solution.

My question is how... Is there any POS-expert out there that could have a solution to my problem?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

After having done something similar based on the scanner (or magnetic card reader) basically being a keyboard and I could listen and handle those keypresses as they were in a certain pattern... I've dont eh following......

Key press pattern...

```
;123123?
```

I wrote the following code to notice the key press at teh main form level, then open / focus the appropriate form field on the ";".  Then take all the other key presses until "?" and take that as "enter".

```
private void EPOSForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    //this captures ";" and gives focus to the member ref for input also escape key
    if (e.KeyValue == 186 || e.KeyValue == 27) {
    textBox.Focus();
    }
}

private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    //this captures ";" and ignores it
    if (e.KeyValue == 186 || e.KeyValue == 191 || e.KeyValue == 27)
    return;
}

private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (textBox.Text.IndexOf(";") != -1) {
        //prevents typing of the last char
    textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace(";", "");
    textBox.Focus();
    textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
    }

    if (textBox.Text.IndexOf("?") != -1) {
        //prevents typing of the last char, but assumes it mean "enter"
    textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace("?", "");
    textBox.Focus();
    textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
    //click button
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Barry and thanks for your answer. Maybe my question was a little vague, I wan't to display the text on the scanners display, not on the screen. You should be able to do this sending escape-sequences to the scanner but I can't get it to work. Someone else that has a clue how it could be done using Microsoft Point Of Service 1.14?